# Items ordered before the date of order of a particular item

Tags: mysql, sqlite

Here is the table I have

```
|Customer|Order Nr.| Items | date of order |
|    1   |    1    | Item1 | date 1        | 
|    1   |    1    | Item2 | date 1        |
|    1   |    2    | Item1 | date 2        |
|    1   |    2    | Item3 | date 2        |
|    1   |    3    | Item6 | date 9        | --> Item 6,   date 9 is reference date
|    1   |    6    | Item5 | date 14       |
|    1   |    7    | Item6 | date 18       | --> Item 6 again, date 18 is not relevant
|    2   |    1    | Item3 | date 4        |
|    2   |    1    | Item5 | date 4        |
|    2   |    2    | Item9 | date 3        |
|    2   |    2    | Item6 | date 3        | --> date 3 is reference date
|    2   |    3    | Item6 | date 4        | --> Item 6 again, date 4 is not relevant
```

I need to get all the orders and items of the customer before the reference date. 
Referenfe date is the date where the `Item6` was ordered for the **first time** by this customer. The list of customers in this table are the ones who ordered `Item6`.

The table must look like:

```
|Customer| Items |
|    1   | Item1 |
|    1   | Item2 |
|    1   | Item3 |
|    2   | Item3 |
|    2   | Item5 |
|    2   | Item9 |
```

***resutlting table should not have the  Item6 info!***

Any suggestion would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a customer *X*, this query looks up the reference date:

```
SELECT min(DateOfOrder)
FROM MyTable
WHERE Customer = X
  AND Items = 'Item6';
```

Now you can use this in a correlated subquery to filter the rows:

```
SELECT Customer,
       Items
FROM MyTable AS T1
WHERE DateOfOrder < (SELECT min(T2.DateOfOrder)
                     FROM MyTable AS T2
                     WHERE T2.Customer = T1.Customer
                       AND T2.Items = 'Item6');
```

Comment: Thanks CL! I got the logic!

Answer (score 1):

This will return the minimum date of Item6 purchase for each customer

```
select  Customer, min(DateOfOrder)
from    yourTable
where   Items = 'Item6'
group by Customer
```

Then you can join it with the original table

```
select  Customer, Items
from    yourTable t1
join    (
            select  Customer, min(DateOfOrder) minDate
            from    yourTable
            where   Items = 'Item6'
            group by Customer
        ) t2
on      t1.Customer = t2.Customer
where   t1.DateOfOrder < t2.minDate
```

Comment: Thanks Stefano! Its very neat!